# seeding with has_one, has_many and through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, seeding

I'm running the rake db:seed command and it doesn't give any errors. However, I'm not finding this Event through the console `Event.find(1)` or through the server `localhost:3000/events/`. I know I'm definitely messing up somewhere. 
the associations:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :lineup
  has_many :artists, :through => :lineup
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

seed.rb:

```
Event.create(name: "The function", 
             date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
             venue: Venue.create(name: "Speakeasy", address: "Lynwood Ave", zip_code: "30312"), 
             lineup: Lineup.create(:artist => Artist.create(name: "DJ Sliink", bio: "jersey club king")), 
             description: "free free free")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that any of the `.create` methods are silently failing validations.

From [the `create` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create):

> The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

Try using `create!` instead; it will raise an exception if the record could not be saved.

I would recommend using using `create!` everywhere in `seeds.rb` to avoid silent failures.

Comment: yep, that helped!! turns out that I have it modeled in such way that a `Lineup` cannot be created without an `Event`